# mouseOut effect with a mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

The following code produces a mask on a web page when hovering over a menu, my question is how do I edit this code to make the mask go away with `mouseout` event? As it sits now I have to click for the mask to go away. Any help is appreciated.

```
<script> 

$(function() {
   
    $("#menuwrapper").mouseover(function() {
       
        $(this).expose();

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() { 

    $("#menuwrapper").mouseover(function() {      
        $(this).expose();  
    });

  $("#menuwrapper").mouseout(function() {     
        $(this).hide();  
    });

});
```

Comment: This made my menu disappear altogether and the mask remained on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Or more succinctly:

```
$("#menuwrapper").hover( 
  function(){ $(this).expose(); },
  function(){ $(this).hide(); } // opposite of expose() function
);
```

Comment: still functioned but didn't remove the mask

Comment: Perhaps you need to attach the mask hiding function to the mouseout event of the mask itself. Without knowing more details it's hard to say.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [expose library](http://churchforallnations.org/multimedia/scrollable/tools/expose.html), you can setup the event like this:

```
$("#menuwrapper").hover( 
  function(){ $(this).expose(); },
  function(){ $(this).unexpose(); } // opposite of expose() function
);
```

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work.  Also, this kind of functionality is easily achieved with the jQuery framework itself (which is what newB is using).